# pandas filter if string in row A contains row b element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say we have this df

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2010, 2020, 2010], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue'], "shirt" : ["red shirt", "green and red shirt", "yellow shirt"] })
```

like this:

```
    year    colors  shirt
0   2010    red     red shirt
1   2020    white   green and red shirt
2   2010    blue    yellow shirt
```

I want to filter out rows in which the "shirt" column contains the "colors" column also considering the "year" column

desired output:

```
year    colors  shirt
    0   2010    red     red shirt
```

I tried this `d[(d.year == 2010) & (d.shirt.str.contains(d.colors))]` but I am getting this error:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

It is a big df that I am working on. How can I solve with some pandas function?

Comment: do a join by pipe on the string contains: `d[(d.year == 2010) & (d.shirt.str.contains('|'.join(d.colors)))]`..?

Comment: @anky what was the reason for the error?

Comment: Actually looking at your example the answer by Rakesh should be more apt, as str contains with a pattern for all rows will even match something not in the current row

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need `df.apply`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2010, 2020, 2010], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue'], "shirt" : ["red shirt", "green and red shirt", "yellow shirt"] })
print(df[(df.year == 2010) & df.apply(lambda x: x.colors in x.shirt, axis=1)])
```

**Output:**

```
   year colors      shirt
0  2010    red  red shirt
```

Comment: I thought about it, I was hoping for some pandas function but this works too!

Comment: @anky sorry i am not able to think on how to use a list comprehension here.

Comment: No Problem , i meant something like: `d[d['year'].eq(2010) & [a in b for a,b in zip(d['colors'],d['shirt'])]]`